# (discord.py) Adding reactions to an embed posted by a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

To preface: I am VERY inexperienced with Python, and have never taken a class for it. This is my first time coding Python/making a discord bot.

Right here I have an embed that is triggered by a specific message. I am using a discord ticket bot (creates new channels that are private to a person who reacted to a message) already (plan to make my own in the future) and every time a new ticket is created, this embed is sent. **I have seen posts on here about adding reactions to an embed, by referencing the channel id on the discord server, however I cannot do this.** The embed is sent to a brand new channel every time I want reactions added. I'm not sure if I don't quite understand Python enough to actually do this, or if it actually CAN'T be done. Regardless, some help would be appreciated in trying to solve this. To be clear: I want to have reactions added along with every embed created (not in one specific channel but ones created on the fly).

```
import discord
import os


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith('Welcome to Parakeets Mods'):
      embed = discord.Embed(title="Product Select", description="React to the emojis corresponding with what you need", color=0xE91E63)
      embed.add_field(name="​", value="<:dmu:841700430764310559> = ***-*** \n\n <:damascus:841700430492860466> = ***-*** \n\n <a:prestige10:841700430010777651> = ***-*** \n\n  <:ruavt:856345494674472980> = ***-*** \n\n ❓ = ***Questions***")
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    #insert add reaction to above embed

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the message you're sending and add a reaction to it

```py
msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
await msg.add_reaction("✅")
```

*PS: You have to pass a unicode emoji when adding a reaction, to get it `\:emoji:` in discord, send and copy the message*

Comment: on mobile you might send ``:emoji:`` (the emoji in a codeblock) to get it
it then looks like this: `<:emoji:12387592034>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add reactions using the `add_reaction("emoji_here")`. you also need to define the message the bot send to make it work.

Reference from the FAQ: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message

Updated Code :

```py
import discord
import os


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith('Welcome to Parakeets Mods'):
      embed = discord.Embed(title="Product Select", description="React to the emojis corresponding with what you need", color=0xE91E63)
      embed.add_field(name="​", value="<:dmu:841700430764310559> = ***-*** \n\n <:damascus:841700430492860466> = ***-*** \n\n <a:prestige10:841700430010777651> = ***-*** \n\n  <:ruavt:856345494674472980> = ***-*** \n\n ❓ = ***Questions***")
      embed_message = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
      await embed_message.add_reaction("")
 

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Thank me later :D